A root finding problem
While solving a partial differential equation, I obtained the following function:
$$ F(z)=(k^2 - z^2)J_1^2(z)-z^2J_0^2(z) \tag 1$$
where $k \in (1, \sqrt2)$ and $z$ is a complex variable. I need to find the roots of the above function (all values of $z$ which would yield $F(z)=0$). Here is what I tried.
I rewrote $(1)$ as:
$$ F(z) = \Big( \sqrt{k^2-z^2} J_1(z) \Big)^2 - \Big( z J_0(z) \Big)^2 \tag 2$$
Using the difference of two squares formula I reformulated $(2)$ as:
$$F(z) = \Big( \sqrt{k^2-z^2} J_1(z) + z J_0(z) \Big) \Big( \sqrt{k^2-z^2} J_1(z) - z J_0(z) \Big) \tag 3$$
Now I reduced my problem to finding the roots of $G(z)$ defined as:
$$ G(z) = \sqrt{k^2-z^2} J_1(z) \pm z J_0(z) \tag 4$$
using the derivative propery $J_1(z)=-J_0'(z)$, I wrote:
$$ G(z) = -\sqrt{k^2-z^2} J_0'(z) \pm z J_0(z) \tag 5$$
My idea to proceed further with this problem was to solve the following differential equation:
$$ -\sqrt{k^2-z^2} f'(z) \pm z f(z) = 0 \tag 6$$
and to find where $f(z)$ and $J_0(z)$ intersect. Using the separation of variables, I found the solution of the above differential equation to be:
$$ f(z) = C e^ {\mp \sqrt{k^2-z^2}} \tag 7 $$
Since I know that $z = 0$ is a root of $(4)$, and $J_0(0)=1$, I found the integration constant to be $C=e^{\pm k}$. This yields:
$$ f(z) = e^ {\pm k \mp \sqrt{k^2-z^2}} \tag 8  $$
Now I need to find all $z_j$ $(j=0,1,2...)$ that satisfy the relation:
$$ J_0(z_j)=e^ {\pm k \mp \sqrt{k^2-z_j^2}} \tag 9$$
However, I don't know how to find these intersection points. I would appreciate help in solving this problem.
